# PHP - Store MySQL result into array from different queries

Tags: php, mysql

For example, the tables structure are as follow:

```
Table 1          Table 2
+------+-----+   +-------+----------+
| Name | Age |   | Class | Location |
+------+-----+   +-------+----------+
| JACK | 15  |   | 205   | LDK      |
+------+-----+   +-------+----------+
| JOHN | 15  |   | 205   | KKD      |
+------+-----+   +-------+----------+
| JESS | 16  |   | 206   | MMA      |
+------+-----+   +-------+----------+
```

And after running 2 `select` query, my expected array should be in this way:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [name] => Jack
        [age] => 15
        [class] => 205
        [location] => LDK
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [name] => John
        [age] => 15
        [class] => 205
        [location] => KKD
    )
    ...
)
```

My code:

```
$sql="select * from table1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $arr[]=$row;
}

$sql2="select * from table2";
$result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $arr[]=$row2;
}
```

But the outcome becomes:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [name] => Jack
        [age] => 15
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [name] => John
        [age] => 15
    )
    ...

    [3] => Array
    (
        [class] => 205
        [location] => LDK
    )
    [4] => Array
    (
        [class] => 205
        [location] => KKD
    )
    ...
)
```

Are there any ways to achieve my expected array outcome ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally there should be a column which links the values in the two tables, then you could just write your query as a `JOIN` and be guaranteed of getting the results you expect, every time you run the code. Given that there isn't one, the best you can do is read both result sets row by row and merge the results of each query:

```
$sql="select * from table1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $arr[]=$row;
}

$sql2 = "select * from table2";
$result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
$rownum = 0;
while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){
    $arr[$rownum] = array_merge($arr[$rownum] ?? [], $row2);
    $rownum++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. The reason i dont use `JOIN` is that the two tables have no relation. The table above shown is just a sample data.